# Remote action (start, stop and make ISO booting

Tags: hp, operating-system

I’ve been searching for this for the last 2 weeks and still not fully get it)…,8; someone could help me i will appreciate so much.

So, i would like to know the way AKA protocol server hosting company would use to make X server able to being managed even when the server is powered off.

Having HP Dl360 G7 server, i am able to power off and power on from iLo 3 Web UI.

My main question is, is there another way of doing this taking in consideration that bunch of our servees are not HP, which make it impossible to use iLo.

I’ve already heard about Wake on Lan method, which is somethings i was not able to find more about this.

Also, is there a a way, from an empty server (no OS installed), to remotely boot up and ISO ?

Thanks alot

Btw, iLo3 doesn’t have API. RESTful are only available for ilo4 and above.

Answer (score -1):

As we make very clear in our first help pages we expect question-askers here to have done some basic research themselves before asking - this took me less than ten seconds to find - [Clicky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)

If you want to power on and force a boot from remote ISO then you're going to need your servers to have some form of IPMI-like option (such as HPE's iLO, Dell's iDRAC, Cisco's CIMC etc.) - Wake on LAN will not do this for you, it'll simply boot a machine, not control that boot. That said if you're a professional you should only be using servers with this functionality anyway and if most/all professional servers come with them.

Oh and your DL360 G7 went end of support four years ago and iLO 3 does indeed have a CLI that can be managed remotely  - [Clicky 2](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c02774508)

Must do better.

Comment: Server can be configured to always boot from network, but network boot could be set up so it defaults to local server booting, and in the event you need to boot from ISO you only change the configuration on the network boot server for the particular server to boot from ISO and reboot the target server. This is how Hetzner seems to be providing their rescue environment, switchable in their control panel.